# How to use Monologue gem in native app (getting posts from Monologue into root app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines, monologue

I'm using the Monologue gem (rails engine for blogging) and mounting it in my app at /blog, I want to get the posts with a certain tag and display those posts on the home page of my app ('/'). From rails c I can get a tag OR a post by doing `Monologue::Tag` or `Monologue::Post` but when I try to do `Monologue::Tag.posts.published` (like how he has the app getting the posts for a specific tag in source) I get "undefined method". I know it's because it's an engine, I'm just not familiar enough with engines to know what the proper syntax for this is?
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the posts for a specific tag right? Then, this is not what you want:

```
Monologue::Tag.posts.published
```

You are not specifying any tag here, you are calling the method `posts` on `Monologue::Tag`, but that is not a specific tag instance, it is the `Monologue::Tag` class.

Once you have a specific tag, you will be able to call `posts.published` on it, or as I see in the [source](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/blob/master/app/models/monologue/tag.rb), you can even call `posts_with_tag`

I guess that in order to try this, you could just get the first tag and then call the method:

```
Monologue::Tag.first.posts.published
```

Edit:

As I told you in the comment, your problem was that you were trying to call the method `posts` to an object that was not of the class `Monologue::Tag` (your model), but of the class `ActiveRecord::Relation` (a collection of `Monologue::Tag` objects).. Doing the `first` works, because is returning the first instance that was found by the `where`.

Another approach, if you know that you just want to fetch one instance, is to call `find` instead of `where`. Like this:

`Monologue::Tag.find_by(name: "Goals")`

This will return an instance of `Monologue::Tag`.

Comment: What I was trying to show is that I can get a tag by calling:
`Monologue::Tag.where(name: "Whatever")`
and that returns a tag, but when I do something like:
`tag = Monologue::Tag.where(name: "whatever")`
and try to do this after:
`tag.posts.published`
I get undefined method

I still get undefined method when trying `Monologue::Tag.first.posts.publushed`

According to edge guides I tried something like this in console:
`Monologue::Tag class_eval do`
  `self.posts.published`
`end`

But it still didn't work

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'posts' for #    <ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Monologue_Tag:0x0000000436ad18>`


Is what I get when I do:


`tag = Monologue::Tag.where(name: "Goals")`


`tag.posts`

Comment: Try this instead ``tag = Monologue::Tag.where(name:'Goals').first`` notice the first

Comment: The ``where`` method doesn't return an object of the class that has defines the ``posts`` method, it teturns (as the error shows) an ActieRecord Relation. That relation contains objects (in your case just one) of the class that knows about the posts method.

Comment: Also, if this solved your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: I still don't quite understand but I'll look more into it. Thank you so much for answering and explaining why this works! I wish I had enough reputation to upvote this.

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify the ``where`` confusion you have.